# Unity suspected floating point error black dots

Tags: c#, floating-point, unity-game-engine, mesh, floating-point-precision

I am creating this puzzle thing, which generates puzzle pieces at runtime (i generate verts, make them into meshes, and texture them all at runtime)

Since i now got a complete puzzle, and after confirming that verts are EXACTLY lined up, i get these tiny tiny black dots when i view my puzzle. They are however nowhere to be seen when you zoom in on them.

### [image: Example]

I suspect this is just a floating point error. If that is the case, I have no idea how to fix it. Any input on this subject is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Smiley

Comment: Do you really expect useful help on the basis of a screenshot?

Comment: @Alex I rest my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stitch the vertices together and use UV mapping to compose your puzzle mesh. That way you will not have this visual artifact.

It's a rendering artifact not a floating point error. You often see this sort of thing when say two wall pieces that are, seemingly, perfectly aligned still show a tiny (pixel wide) gap.

Another way to solve this would be to overlap the puzzle pieces a little bit. Of course you must also take z order into account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not really have the ability to "stitch" them together easily. And overlapping will most likely create a distortion in the puzzle image. But if there is no other option, what scale would you recommend to make this tiny thing disappear?

Comment: After some tests, any scale from 1.00001 to 1.1 doesn't help a bit. 1.1 makes it even worse though. everything below that doesn't seem to do a whole lot.

Comment: No the issue is that these meshes are not part of one connected body of triangles. It's not really Unity's fault, most likely you will encounter this artifacts in any 3D engine. The only way of doing this (that I know of) is to produce a single mesh with all the vertices connected.

Comment: Let us accept faith then. I will try one last thing, which is auto stitching unity has, to just stitch all the fronts together in the end. But it would require a buttload of code to get it to work right.

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot about that. I don't see why it wouldn't work. Maybe this will help too http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/423236/will-combinemeshes-stitch-2-meshes-together.html

Comment: I found a better solution IF i can execute it, i will try to make a new question about it though. It would involve not rendering the sides of the pieces when they are close to each other (it can be achieved with the camera FAR plane being REALLY close to the front of the piece. making the sides invisible to the camera. There must be a way to do this manually within some cube as well.